# SQL Server stored procedure dynamic SQL in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I have written a stored procedure that accepts one parameter.

```
Request_ID int = 0
```

Later, in my `WHERE` clause, I need to accomplish the following.

I don't know how to describe it, but you can see what I'm trying to do with this completely made up  pseudo-code:

```
WHERE isNull(a.Target_Department, '') <> ''
  AND isNull(a.Resolved_Date, '') = ''
  AND isNull(c.Request_Archived, '') <> 'Y'
  AND IF @Request_ID = 0 
        THEN Request_ID > 0 
        ELSE Request_ID = @Request_ID
    END
```

Basically, if a specific `request_ID` is supplied, I want the `WHERE` clause to narrow to only that specific `Request_ID`. Otherwise, I want all of them.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -->

```
WHERE
    (@Request_ID IS NULL OR Request_ID=@RequestID)
```

OR

```
WHERE
    (@Request_ID=0 OR Request_ID=@RequestID)
```

Comment: That does it!  I got an almost identical answer to another question last week.  I sometimes do not look at two "AND" options as a two separate conditions that can be tested individually.

And I also did not know you could test variables in the where clause of a query against a table.

Answer (score 1):

```
and isnull(nullif(@RequestId,0),RequestId)=RequestId
```